# Getting keys from NSDictionary in ordered manner

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sorting, nsdictionary

I am having JSON Response like this :

```
 {
    "graphdata": {
        "2018-02-27 to 2018-03-05": {
            "historical": 2.93,
            "datewise": 2.82,
            "ordno": 3595,
            "revno": 89
        },
        "2018-03-06 to 2018-03-12": {
            "historical": 2.92,
            "datewise": 2.62,
            "ordno": 3780,
            "revno": 87
        },
        "2018-03-13 to 2018-03-19": {
            "historical": 2.92,
            "datewise": 3.16,
            "ordno": 3742,
            "revno": 86
        },
        "2018-03-20 to 2018-03-26": {
            "historical": 2.93,
            "datewise": 3.17,
            "ordno": 3745,
            "revno": 70
        },
        "2018-03-27 to 2018-04-02": {
            "historical": 2.93,
            "datewise": 3.08,
            "ordno": 4242,
            "revno": 84
        },
        "2018-04-03 to 2018-04-09": {
            "historical": 2.93,
            "datewise": 3.29,
            "ordno": 3575,
            "revno": 79
        },
        "2018-04-10 to 2018-04-16": {
            "historical": 2.94,
            "datewise": 3.19,
            "ordno": 3629,
            "revno": 69
        },
        "2018-04-17 to 2018-04-23": {
            "historical": 2.94,
            "datewise": 3.33,
            "ordno": 4211,
            "revno": 42
        },
        "2018-04-24 to 2018-04-30": {
            "historical": 2.94,
            "datewise": 0,
            "ordno": 1638,
            "revno": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i use allKeys method I am getting Keys in unordered manner like this :

```
(
    "2018-03-13 to 2018-03-19",
    "2018-04-03 to 2018-04-09",
    "2018-03-20 to 2018-03-26",
    "2018-04-10 to 2018-04-16",
    "2018-04-17 to 2018-04-23",
    "2018-04-24 to 2018-04-30",
    "2018-03-27 to 2018-04-02",
    "2018-02-27 to 2018-03-05",
    "2018-03-06 to 2018-03-12"
)
```

How to get these in ordered manner like starting should be from :         "2018-02-27 to 2018-03-05",

Comment: you may use sort Descriptor http://nshipster.com/nssortdescriptor/ couple of examples are available here.

Comment: dictionary always in the inorder format, if you need in the order format, then use `Sort` concept

Comment: shivam can you please share that array iterates?. where you add dates from dict  because i faced same probelm earlier.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik thanks for sharing info. It solves my problem.

Comment: @RB1509 I didn't got you what u are asking?

Comment: here you dont want to sort array because it will give direct response as well as your json data.

Comment: and your json has right order so you dont want sort.if your json data are inorder than you want to sort get it or not?

Comment: @RB1509 Yes my json has right order. But I need all these keys separately  in same manner as i am receiving. For getting All keys I think "dict[all keys]" is the option which results in unordered format.  I am using these keys to draw some Graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169917/discussion-between-rb1509-and-shivam-tripathi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using sortedArrayUsingComparator :

```
   NSArray *sortedKeys = [[myDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        return [a compare:b];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    NSDate *d1 = [df dateFromString: obj1];
    NSDate *d2 = [df dateFromString: obj2];
    return [d1 compare: d2];
}];
```

Note : Set formate of date According to your date

Answer (score 0):

```
(((jsonDict.object(forKey: "graphdata") as! NSDictionary).allKeys) as! [String]).sorted(by: <) as NSArray
```

here jsonDict is your parent NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

Every Dictionary is an unordered collection of key-value pairs.

> Use a [DictionaryLiteral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionaryliteral) instance when you need an ordered
>   collection of key-value pairs and don’t require the fast key lookup
>   that the Dictionary type provides.

Comment: is this possible to add some sample